# It is possible to connect Oracle to Quartz back-end database

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quarts to schedule the jobs..
Back-end database is now `sql` server

It is possible to connect to `Oracle` database. if yes how..?

Comment: Same way you did with SQL Server?

Comment: Its possible to use Oracle as Quartz database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use it.

follow this tutorial : http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/job-stores.html

- Run Oracle table creation sqls contained in quartz.net package.
- Modify Quartz.Config

  ```
  quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = table prefix , default is QRTZ_

  quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDatasource

  quartz.dataSource.myDatasource.connectionString = connection string

  quartz.dataSource.myDatasource.provider = OracleClient-20
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@polarbear:1521:dev
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = quartz
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = quartz
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 5
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validationQuery=select 0 from dual
```

[Quartz Documentation](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering)